# Finding max rectangle of 0's in an binary 2D array

Tags: c

I just started learning C code and I'm kinda stuck with this question.
So the details are:

1. I need to scan 2 numbers that represent the dimensions of my 2D array. ( Can do)
2. Need to get an input from the user of 0's and 1's and insert them in the rows of the 2D array. (don't need to handle errors: the input is only 1 and 0 and the exact number that the array can contain)
3. Need to print the max rectangle area of 0's in the array. (If there is a rectangle of 6 0's I need to print 6)

I know that the histogram may help me to do so but I just don't understand how to convert it to the code for 0's. and the 2cd step also won't work for me (the print at the end of the code is just for checking)

#include "stdafx.h"

#include 
   #define N 30

int main()

{

```
   printf("Enter dimentions:\n");

   int i, j, row, col, Mat[N][N], SumMat[N][N];
   int temp=0, curr;
   scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
   for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
           scanf("%d", &Mat[i][j]);
       }
   }
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        for (i = row; i < 0; i--) {
              if (*Mat[i][j] == 0) {
                  temp += 1;
                  SumMat[i][j] = temp;
              }
              else
              {
                  temp = 0;
              }
         }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Here is my new code, I debug it and I saw that the value inside the array is garbage values( after I scanned the input from the user) and I can't figure out why is that. should I use pointers somehow?
Glad for anyone to check my code

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: I'm just rewriting it over and over, I will show u my last try soon when ill finish

Comment: And again no 1 asked for a code, I asked for help understanding the concept of how to approach the task.